# How to simply query vimeo for video information with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

We are tring to get information about a video via the Vimeo API. i.e. By using 
 a jquery $.ajax get request to:

```
vimeo.com/api/v2/video/253742573.json
```

However, this won't work on Internet Explorer 11, as it complains about CORS issues. Naturally, we can't control what HTTP headers the Vimeo replies with to correct this.

- Is this a known issue with the Vimeo player?
- Is there a better way to query Vimeo for information on a Video with Javascript over HTTP?
- If there is, where can we find a good example of this?

Comment: Where did you find the API usage ? I google Vimeo API and I found this - https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

Comment: The Vimeo Simple API (with the uri structure https://vimeo.com/api/v2) is deprecated and no longer supported by Vimeo. What specific metadata do you need back about your Vimeo video? You might be able to use oEmbed, depending on the video and its privacy.

Comment: @TommyPenner We need to be able to look up the thumbnail URL and embed the video.

Comment: @dysontesters If that's all you need, then Vimeo's oEmbed implementation should be a good solution: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue with IE. The response headers from Vimeo are correct.

I've seen similar issues with various browsers over the years.
The solution that I've used in the past is to implement a pass-through on my own server. In that scenario, my JS in the browser would no longer call `vimeo.com/api/v2...` directly. Instead, it would call `mydomain.com/vimeoapi/api/v2...` and my server (which doesn't care about CORS) will retrieve the JSON from Vimeo and pass it back to the JS in the browser.

Honestly, this solution makes me grind my teeth every time (WHY MUST I MAKE ARCHITECTURAL COMPROMISES FOR JUST ONE BROWSER! CURS YOU, STARS!), but I've done it a handful of times now and it plays out reasonably well. It's a straight-forward solution that can be done quickly, and if you find a preferable solution, it's easy to switch this out again.